# lambda expression giving compile time error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda

This is what I am trying:

```
testMethod(){
driver.findElement(By.xpath()).sendKeys(password=()->TestData.getNewPassword());
}
```

But it is giving me compile time error `The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`. What wrong am I doing?

Secondly: What different am I doing here? Because I can simply pass `TestData.getNewPassword()` instead of `password=()->TestData.getNewPassword()`, unless I can use lambda expressions as a class variable and so I will use `password` throughout the class in all test methods.

Excuse me, if you see two questions in one go.

Comment: `sendKeys` accepts a string, but you're trying to pass it a lambda (while simultaneously assigning it to a variable called `password`)...?

Comment: I think this how it should be. Saw it here https://youtu.be/nUIAvs4OEkM?t=6m45s

Comment: Yes, you can assign a lambda to a variable (you don't *have* to, but you *can*). It has nothing whatsoever to do with my comment above. If you want to pass the result of calling `TestData.getNewPassword()` into `sendKeys`, just do that. No need for a lambda at all.

Comment: If I am doing right, why it is giving an error?

Comment: Please read the comments again above: You're correctly creating a lambda and assigning it to a variable (assuming you have an in-scope `password`) variable. But **that's not what `sendKeys` expects**. It expects a **string**, not a lambda.

Comment: For the sake of an answer, not bad practice or good practice, can you put it in an answer if it has to be done using lambda? It will help me to understand the use of lambda.

Comment: It's nothing to do with good or bad practice. Again: What you pass `sendKeys` should be a string. How you get the string is entirely up to you. Passing in a lambda will not work. If that answers your question, just delete it; it's unlikely to be of any use to others in the future.

Comment: It is giving an error in a separate line of code also i.e. without using it for .sendKeys.
`password=()->TestData.getNewPassword()`